# Create a MySQL view table on one database but fill with results from another database

Tags: migrations, database

I have 2 databases: `myshop` (the Drupal db) and `myshop_migrate` (the Migrate db).  To make things tricky - both databases reside on different AWS instances.

I need to create a `mysql view` on `myshop` to hold a `SELECT *` query from the `myshop_migrate` database.

Currently, I have:

```
db_set_active('myshop_migrate_db'); //reference migrate db
$query = db_query('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myshop_migrate_stock_commerce AS SELECT * FROM myshop_migrate.stock_commerce');
```

- but this just creates the VIEW table on the myshop_migrate database (as the current active db is referencing myshop_migrate)..

```
db_set_active(); //default drupal db
$query = db_query('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myshop_migrate_stock_commerce AS SELECT * FROM myshop_migrate.stock_commerce');
```

- This wont work because `myshop_migrate.stock_commerce` doesn't exist on the myshop database!

Completely lost on this.  Can I somehow store the result of the SELECT * from myshop_migrate in a variable? Switch the active db, create a view table on myshop, then import the variable into the table?

Comment: can these 2 databases use a shared db username and password ? If yes, you can change your query to like: `create or replace view myshop.myshop_migrate_stock_commerce as select * from myshop_migrate_db.stock_commerce`  eg in your query you just supply the DB names literally, this is supported by mysql. Of course if you can share a db user/pass then there's no need for the View ...

Comment: thanks for the feedback - by share db user/pass, do you mean match them up so they're both the same on each db? (apologies - lacking in mysql knowhow!).  If so, I've tried this.. but just get the following error: `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myshop_migrate.stock_commerce' doesn't exist`.. Not sure if what I'm trying to achieve is doable.  I can't alter connections whilst querying, so can't pluck data from both.. Annoying

Comment: no i'm saying if you have `database1` and `database2` just re-use a single database user between the two of them: `grant all priviledges on database1.* to USERNAME@localhost; grant all priviledges on database2.* to USERNAME@localhost;`. Here is an example to create a db user for Debian http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-create-a-mysql-database-and-set-privileges-to-a-user/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that view is only a SELECT on that table, try using a FEDERATED table instead.

I never had the chance to use it so far, but it should go like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myshop_migrate ( exactly like myshop table )
ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=same of myshop
CONNECTION='mysql://user@host:9306/myshop_migrated/stock_commerce';
```

where user and host are those of the remote server.

create it from phpmyadmin or mysql workbench, just to have additional options and hints that drupal can't give you.

Comment: Oh, the FEDERATED engine is usually disabled, turn it on, if AWS lets you.